# PHP - Changing a value in a JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have the below php code that receives some variables from another page (sent via POST).

Based on the Ad_id and Name... i'm trying to toggle the status between 'active or 'inactive'.

However when i execute this (with correct POST data)... it doesn't seem to update anything. What am i doing wrong?

e.g. When i send through a valid ad, name & status... then go and check the JSON file, it asn't toggled 'active' to 'inactive'.

PHP:

```
<?php

// Get the post variables
$ad_id = $_GET['ad']; 
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$status = $_GET['status']; 

// Get the JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('test.json');

// Decode Json into an array
$json = json_decode($json,true);

// Within the array.. find the ad that matches the POST variable.
foreach ($json['ads'] as $ad) {
    if ($ad['id'] == $ad_id) {

        // Within that Ad... find the candidate that matches the POST variable.
        foreach ($ad['candidates'] as $candidate) {
            if ($candidate['name'] == $name) {

                // Within that candidate... check the value of 'status'.
                if ($candidate['status'] == 'active') {

                    // If active, update the status to 'inactive'.
                    $candidate['status'] = 'inactive';

                } else {

                    // If inactive, update the status to 'active'.
                    $candidate['status'] = 'active';

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

// Encode the array as JSON again
$json = json_encode($json);

// Save the JSON back to the server
file_put_contents('test.json', $json, LOCK_EX);

?>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "ads": [
        {
            "id": "12345678",
            "hirername": "Demo Bar",
            "candidates": [
                {
                    "status": "active",
                    "name": "Gregory Jones",
                    "dist": "Richmond (4km away)",
                    "exp1": "Barman at City Bar for 2 years",
                    "avail1": "Mon to Fri - Morning, Evening & Night",
                    "visa": "Australian Citizen",
                    "call": "0413451222"
                },
                {
                    "status": "active",
                    "name": "Jackie Linton",
                    "dist": "Box Hill (13km away)",
                    "exp1": "Bar girl at Collins Bar for 1 year",
                    "avail1": "Mon to Fri - Morning & Evening",
                    "visa": "Working holiday visa",
                    "call": "0413456555"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which part is not working??

Comment: When i send through a valid ad, name & status... then go and check the JSON file, it asn't toggled 'active' to 'inactive'.

Comment: You should iterate your data by links with `foreach($items as &$item)` syntax. Then all changes will be in the original structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate your data by links with `foreach($items as &$item)` syntax.
Then all changes will be in the original structure.

Now, you create copies, while iterate, modify copies, and nothing changed.

```
// Get the post variables
$ad_id = $_GET['ad']; 
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$status = $_GET['status']; 

// Get the JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('test.json');

// Decode Json into an array
$json = json_decode($json,true);

// Within the array.. find the ad that matches the POST variable.
foreach ($json['ads'] as &$ad) {
    if ($ad['id'] == $ad_id) {

        // Within that Ad... find the candidate that matches the POST variable.
        foreach ($ad['candidates'] as &$candidate) {
            if ($candidate['name'] == $name) {

                // Within that candidate... check the value of 'status'.
                if ($candidate['status'] == 'active') {

                    // If active, update the status to 'inactive'.
                    $candidate['status'] = 'inactive';

                } else {

                    // If inactive, update the status to 'active'.
                    $candidate['status'] = 'active';
                    }

            }

        }

    }

}

// Encode the array as JSON again
$json = json_encode($json);

// Save the JSON back to the server
file_put_contents('test.json', $json, LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code. What you have done for reading and comparing values is correct.

But while writing, you have not used the status for `$json` variable.

You are writing as it is.

```
if ($candidate['status'] == 'active') {
     $candidate['status'] = 'inactive';
} else {
     $candidate['status'] = 'active';
}
```

Above you are using variable as `$candidate`.

While writing to file ,

```
$json = json_encode($json);  <------- $json is used. Where is $candidate??
$ret = file_put_contents('test.json', $json, LOCK_EX);
```

**EDIT**

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$i = 0;
$candidate1 = array();
// Within the array.. find the ad that matches the POST variable.
foreach ($json['ads'] as $ad) {
    if ($ad['id'] == $ad_id) {
        $candidate1["id"] = $ad["id"];
        $candidate1["hirername"] = $ad["hirername"];

        // Within that Ad... find the candidate that matches the POST variable.
        foreach ($ad['candidates'] as $candidate) {
            if ($candidate['name'] == $name) {
                $candidate1[$i] = $candidate;
                $candidate['status'] == 'active' ? $candidate1[$i]['status'] = 'inactive' : $candidate1[$i]['status'] = 'active';
            } else {
                $candidate1[$i] = $candidate;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

$json = json_encode($candidate1); 
$ret = file_put_contents('test.json', $json, LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: I want to write the whole $json (including my change) back to test.json... not just $candidate. Do i need to write it differently?

Comment: you shud take all values from `$json` to `$candidate` and then write to your file.

Comment: Thanks. How do i do this? Could you provide an example please?

Comment: You ate not taking any values to $candidate.. You shud assign the values to that variable....

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand. Could you please provide example code of how to do what you are suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: @RobAlford check the edited answer. It should help you.

Comment: Thankyou - But in your example, aren't you creating a new array with just the details of the single Ad/Candidate... and then encoding that and putting it back to the json on the server?  I want to make sure that the whole original json is kept, it's just the status of the one candidate that is changed?

Comment: Also - i just updated and executed... and it replaced the json file with an empty array e.g. [ ].

Comment: Its working for me... `print_r($candidate1);` and check what is getting inserted to that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Problem:
 *
 * - We have 2 variables
 *   $adId: The id of the ad
 *   $name: The name of the candidate
 *
 * - We want to update the status of the candidate depending the current status
 */

// Fake JSON datas
$json = '{

  "ads": [
    {
      "id": "238",
      "hirername": "Demo Bar",
      "candidates": [
        {
          "status": "active",
          "name": "Gregory Jones"
        },
        {
          "status": "active",
          "name": "Jackie Linton"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "239",
      "hirername": "Apple",
      "candidates": [
        {
          "status": "inactive",
          "name": "Steve jobs"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  }';

// Input variables
$adId = 238;
$name = 'Jackie Linton';

// Convert json as an array (we use true as a second param for that)
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// We fetch only the ads entity from the array
$ads = $data['ads'];

// Loop the ads
foreach ($ads as $adIndex => $ad)
{

  // Check if it's the right ad
  if ($ad['id'] == $adId)
  {
    // Loop candidates
    foreach ($ad['candidates'] as $candidateIndex => $candidate)
    {

      // Sanitize strings for a good check
      $name = trim(strtolower($name));
      $candidateName = trim(strtolower($candidate['name']));

      // We found the right candidate
      if ($name == $candidateName)
      {


        // Change status
        if ($candidate['status'] == 'inactive')
        {
          $data['ads'][$adIndex]['candidates'][$candidateIndex]['status'] = 'active';
        }
        else
        {
          $data['ads'][$adIndex]['candidates'][$candidateIndex]['status'] = 'inactive';
        }

      }

    }

  }

}

// We changed the status.
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

With that code (tested and working) you will understand your problem: 
- You were saving the data in a "local" variable rather than your global JSON.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Now that we've updated $ads... how do we get this back into $data or $ json... and then do a file_put_contents to put it back onto the server?

Comment: In my example the variable $data is your JSON as an array with the status updated. Just encode it back as a JSON and save it ;)